# Wait for code to complete and then execute another piece

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, async-await, fetch

Hello everyone i'am trying to download multiple images and put them in an .zip file. That part works just fine but if every images is downloaded i need to download the .zip file to my browser, but the problem is that the code keeps going and download my .zip file before my images are all downloaded. So please can anyone help me?

This is my code for so far:

```
// Make a new Zip file
  var zip = new JSZip();
  var instanceDuplicate = this;
  var storageRef = storage.ref("qavi" + order_number);
  var imageRef = storageRef.child(order_number + ".jpg");
  storageRef
  .listAll()
  .then(function(result) {
    var zip = new JSZip();
    result.items.forEach(function (imageRef) {
      // get download url
      imageRef
      .getDownloadURL()
      .then(function(url) {
        console.log(url);
        const proxyUrl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
        fetch(proxyUrl + url, {
          method: 'GET',
        }).then(function(resp) {
           return resp.blob();
        }).then(function(blob) {
            const newBlob = new Blob([blob], { type: "image/.jpg", charset: "UTF-8" })
            zip.file(imageRef.name, newBlob);
        })
      })
    })
  })
  zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
  .then(function(content) {
    saveAs(content, order_number + ".zip");
  })
},
```

wat i tried with async/await:

```
 async DownloadZip(order_number) {
  // Make a new Zip file
  var zip = new JSZip();
  zip = await this.downloadAllImages(order_number, zip)
  zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
  .then(function(content) {
    saveAs(content, order_number + ".zip");
  })
},
```

I also tried it with another method and tried await/async but din't work for me
someone who can explain me what i can do about it?

Comment: You should read about promise chaining. Nested `then` calls are often unnecessary. And regarding your question, you should have a look at `Promise.all`.

Comment: Hi @str can you please explain me how i do that?

Comment: You're never waiting for the promise from the chain that starts with `imageRef.getDownloadURL()`. Can you please show us your approach with `async`/`await`?

Comment: @Bergi I edited my post so you can see what i tried